# Рассчитать количество дней/часов/минут/секунд между двумя датами

Tags: java, дата

Есть переменная, содержащая System.currentTimeMillis() на момент запуска приложения
Необходимо рассчитать сколько дней, часов минут и секунд прошло на текущий момент

```java
long time_up = System.currentTimeMillis();
.....
long difference = time_up - System.currentTimeMillis();
....
?
```

Comment: uptime: 0 дней, 0 часов, 1 минут, 78 секунд
Хотелось бы не общее количество секунд/минут и т.д, а по обычному. 0 дней, 0 часов, 1 минут, 18 секунд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что имелось в виду, то как-то так.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

long timeUp = format.parse("2016/01/01 00:00:00").getTime();
long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeUp;

long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(diffDays + " дней, ");
sb.append(diffHours + " часов, ");
sb.append(diffMinutes + " минут, ");
sb.append(diffSeconds + " секунд");

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 8):

Вы можете воспользоваться классом java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.
Используйте методы toSeconds, toMinutes, toHours, toDays.

```
d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);

System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");         
System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
```